# Complex intergration. can not match the soultionsheet

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

i can not get the same answer as the soultionsheet and i dont know how. this is the soultionsheet:
[image]

i do get it right to the second line, but the third line of my work do not match the third line in the solution. i do not know where the n^2 comes from in the third line of the solution. i tought this:
[image]

Comment: I also tired this, but i do not get the same answer:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA5yJ.jpg

Comment: On the second line they integrate by parts again.  The first term there is zero.

Comment: See it?  It's right.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a negative symbol. If you take $dv=e^{-inx}$ then as you said $v=-\frac{1}{in}e^{-inx}$, so in the formula as we have $uv-\int vdu$, we have $-\int 2x(-\frac{1}{in}e^{-inx})=\int2x\frac{1}{in}e^{-inx}$, instead of $-\int 2x\frac{1}{in}e^{-inx}$ as you wrote